# How can i store data in database in android application on Qt?

Tags: qt

I have made one android application in Qt.that  employee registration form application. where i distribute this app to other employee they will details (like name, age, salary etc) and that data will be save in one database so where i can access it.

is anyone have idea about?
thanks

Comment: What is your exact problem?

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking to store employee details entered in many mobile devices in one place you will need to have a database your app can all write to.

One way would be to have a server running something like MySQL and a web server. You send the data from the mobile app to the web server using an HTTP POST and some code on the server extracts the data from the POST and inserts it into the database.

If you need to show the data in the database on a mobile app, you can use an HTTP GET adding parameters to the end of the query.  Some code on the server interprets the GET string, extracts data from the database and sends it as part of the result.

There will be a temptation to connect directly from your mobile app to the database on the server using something like ODBC.  Don't do this, its a bad idea. Always have an intermediary application on the server side to give you some insulation against database attacks.  If your application is for more than just internal company use, consider having the database on a separate server and configured to accept connections only from the web server.

As you are sending personal and private information (age, salary etc), ensure you encrypt your data properly when its "in flight".

Hopefully this will give you a few pointers to get you started.  The question is really quite broad.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Vincent its really helpful i am doing in that way